# Adding content to Page settings rather than Block settings

Tags: block-editor

I have a Gutenberg editor. Some content of the page is global, and not relevant to an individual block. I'd like to add content to the page settings:

[image]

I can see how you can add a [plugin that creates a secondary sidebar](https://wpandajax.com/series/building-a-gutenberg-sidebar/lessons/gutenberg-sidebar-setting-up-the-sidebar/) using `registerPlugin`, however is there a way to hook into and add settings to the Page settings sidebar?

Answer (score 1):

Ahh — I found it. It is called the `PluginDocumentSettingPanel` and can be imported from `@wordpress/edit-post`.

```
import { registerPlugin } from '@wordpress/plugins';
import { PluginDocumentSettingPanel } from '@wordpress/edit-post';
 
const PluginDocumentSettingPanelDemo = () => (
    <PluginDocumentSettingPanel
        name="custom-panel"
        title="Custom Panel"
        className="custom-panel"
    >
        Custom Panel Contents
    </PluginDocumentSettingPanel>
);
 
registerPlugin( 'plugin-document-setting-panel-demo', {
    render: PluginDocumentSettingPanelDemo,
    icon: 'palmtree',
} );
```